# What is this area for and why the content inside it isn't showing correctly?

Tags: fringe

I'm using GNU Emacs with Doom. When using, I noticed an area placed before the line numbers. <s>I don't know the name of the area.</s> It is called "fringe". It is used by `vi-tilde-fringe-mode`, `magit` and `dap-mode`. However, the content inside it isn't rendered properly in GUI, and the area is not shown in the terminal.

The image: (see the characters appearing before `Head` and `Recent`, looks like `>` and `v`)

[image: The image]

Is it normal is a problem? If it is a problem, how can I fix it?

I'm using:

- Emacs: 27.1
- Doom: 2.0.9

Comment: If you place cursor on `>` or `v` and then press tab key or click with mouse, do the characters toggle between each other?

Comment: @Melioratus Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to EmacsSE.  This area is called the *fringe* and looks a little odd if it is not wide enough.  The default is 8 pixels and can be achieved simply by putting

```
(fringe-mode)
```

in your init file.  Check the docs for `fringe-mode` to learn more or search the manual for `Window Fringes`.

Comment: I tried that, but due to a ``fringe-mode`` command is hard-coded into Doom's ``:ui vc-gutter``, I have to create a clone of that module for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to fix the problem. [@FranBurstall's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64175/32162) is correct, but it breaks when `:ui vc-gutter` module is enabled. A workaround is to set `+vc-gutter-default-style` to `nil`, which disables the optional UI enhancements. So I had to add this to my `config.el`:

```
(setq +vc-gutter-default-style nil)
(fringe-mode nil)
```

However, I missed the icons shown by the module on the fringe. So I added this to my `config.el` as well: (optional)

```
(after! git-gutter-fringe
  (setq-default fringes-outside-margins t)
  (define-fringe-bitmap 'git-gutter-fr:added [224] nil nil '(center repeated))
  (define-fringe-bitmap 'git-gutter-fr:modified [224] nil nil '(center repeated))
  (define-fringe-bitmap 'git-gutter-fr:deleted [128 192 224 240] nil nil 'bottom))
```