# How can I remove extra gray line at left and right margin in Emacs GUI app?

Tags: gui-emacs, fringe

In macOS Monterey I am using Emacs inside [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com) and also Emacs.app (as gui).

In the Emacs.app itself there is extra space before each line.
That is actually caused by a gray line in the margin.

=> output of `command emacs -Q` in Emacs.app.

[image]

---

When the color of gray line changed to background color it seems like there is a extra indent before each line.

Comparasion views, top terminal is emacs inside iTerm2 and below terminal is Emacs.app itself:

[image]

Is it possible to remove that extra gray box at left and also right margin?

Comment: There are multiple duplicates, it seems. e.g., https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/64172.

Comment: This also answers my question but its on different platform: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373826/how-to-disable-fringe-in-emacs

Comment: It needs more Close votes to close it as a duplicate. Perhaps you can just delete it?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. By the time people discover that a question isn't needed (a dup or other reason), someone has already answered it. And the simpler the question is, the more likely that someone submits an answer quickly, and the more likely the Q is to be a dup. And for some reason this site requires more than a few close votes. So... Anyway, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fringes.html

**14.14 Window Fringes**

"*On graphical displays, each Emacs window normally has narrow fringes on the left and right edges. The fringes are used to display symbols that provide information about the text in the window. You can type `M-x fringe-mode` to toggle display of the fringes or to modify their width. This command affects fringes in all frames; to modify fringes on the selected frame only, use `M-x set-fringe-style`. You can make your changes to the fringes permanent by customizing the variable `fringe-mode`.*"

Comment: Thanks, `(set-fringe-mode 0)` is what I was looking for.